# Write Selected Listbox values to sheet, only one selection is being written

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, selection

I am trying to write the selected values form a listbox to a sheet in excel. Only the first selected value is being written.

The code segment being used is:

```
numofformulas = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets("Costs").Range("D:D")) - 1
k = 0
For i = 0 To numofformulas
    If UserForm3.ListBox1.Selected(i) = True Then
        Sheets("PriceSheet").Cells(k + 7, 3) = UserForm3.ListBox1.List(i)
        k = k + 1
    End If
Next i
```

I was stepping through the code and realized that **after** the:

```
Sheets("PriceSheet").Cells(k + 7, 3) = UserForm3.ListBox1.List(i)
```

line the selection is cleared and they all revert to false so only the first line is writing to the cells. any idea how to stop that clearing?

Comment: why is numofformulas calculated from a worksheet, and not from the userform3.listbox1.listcount value? debug.print the number you are getting to see if it is what you think.

Comment: The selected(i) values are all false. and the list(i) values are just all the values on the list. The only reason I didnt use the listcount property is because I didn't realize it existed until I'd written that line of code hah. I'm a novice, sorry

Comment: did you set the listbox to multiSelect = true?  Otherwise only one will the true.

Comment: Yes. I tried multiselect and multiselect extended. Neither worked.

Comment: i was stepping through the code and realized that after the: Sheets("PriceSheet").Cells(k + 7, 3) = UserForm3.ListBox1.List(i) line the selection is cleared and they all revert to false

Comment: any modification to the list box's content will reset the selected values for the entire listbox.  If the list box is using rowSource, and the data in that range changes, the selected values are cleared.  If you update a column in a multi column list box, the selected values are cleared.  How is the content of the listbox set?

Answer (score 0):

Here are the proper settings for check list.

**ListStyle**

[image: ListStyle Property]

**MultiSelect**

[image: MultiSelect Property]

Comment: didn't work with these settings either

Comment: If you send me a download link, I'll fix it for you.